# How to determine structure stiffness of a damped 1D system with acceleration - time graph?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, dissipation

Consider a damped system with only acceleration - time data is available, how to determine the structure stiffness (k)?  Mass of the structure is also known. It moves in a horizontal direction, like a horizontal mass-spring-damper model. 
The y-axis should be acceleration instead of displacement for the image.

[image]